# c# Asp.NET mvc view create element's database dynamic

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

i have a problem, I'd like to create a dynamic page to Create a element in database.
My idea is :I have a database with 8 columns but for defaul i edit first 4 columns and if i click a link it is created a text box for 5' columns up to 8 columns.

```
> @model Generate_database.Models.Recipe
> 
> @{
>     ViewData["Title"] = "Create"; }
> 
> <h1>Create</h1>
> 
> <h4>Recipe</h4> <hr /> <div class="row">
>     <div class="col-md-4">
>         <form asp-action="Create">
>             <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
>             <div class="form-group">
>                 <label asp-for="RecipeName" class="control-label"></label>
>                 <input asp-for="RecipeName" class="form-control" />
>                 <span asp-validation-for="RecipeName" class="text-danger"></span>
>             </div>
>             <div class="form-group">
>                 <label asp-for="RecipeTimer" class="control-label"></label>
>                 <input asp-for="RecipeTimer" class="form-control" />
>                 <span asp-validation-for="RecipeTimer" class="text-danger"></span>
>             </div>
>             <div class="form-group">
>                 <label asp-for="ComponentID_1" class="control-label"></label>
>                 <select asp-for="ComponentID_1" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ComponentID_1"></select>
>             </div>
>             <div class="form-group">
>                 <label asp-for="RecipeInputWeight_1" class="control-label"></label>
>                 <input asp-for="RecipeInputWeight_1" class="form-control" />
>                 <span asp-validation-for="RecipeInputWeight_1" class="text-danger"></span>
>             </div>
> 
>             <div class="form-group">
>                 <label asp-for="ComponentID_2" class="control-label"></label>
>                 <select asp-for="ComponentID_2" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ComponentID_2"></select>
>             </div>
>             <div class="form-group">
>                 <label asp-for="RecipeInputWeight_2" class="control-label"></label>
>                 <input asp-for="RecipeInputWeight_2" class="form-control" />
>                 <span asp-validation-for="RecipeInputWeight_2" class="text-danger">></span>
></div>
> "A link to edit new box"
```

can this be created?

EDIT:
Can i make a code with if i click a button compare a new label and select box? i think use a javascript but I can't get it to work.
*code*

> 

```
<!--<script>
    var counter = 1;
    $(".btnAdd").click(function ()  {-->
        @*//var r0 = '<label>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ComponentID_2) </label>';*@
        <!--var r1 = @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => modelItem.RecipeInputWeight_2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } });
        //var r2 = '<label asp-for="ComponentID_2" class="control-label"></label>';
        //var r3 = '<select asp-for="ComponentID_2" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ComponentID_2"></select>';
        //var r4 = '</div>';
        //var r5 = '<div class="form-group">';
        //var r6 = '<label asp-for="RecipeInputWeight_2" class="control-label"></label>';
        //var r7 = '<input asp-for="RecipeInputWeight_2" class="form-control" value="0" />';
        //var r8 = '<span asp-validation-for="RecipeInputWeight_2" class="text-danger"></span>';
        //var r9 = '</div >';
        $("form").append('<div>'+r1+'</div>');
        });-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I was you, I would just have 1 field in the db then just use json or xml to serialise and deserialise, you can then easily extend this going forward without too much pain.

if you want start quicker using your existing model then just use something like this and then you can see the structure as well.  I am sure there similar online tools for xml, but that should hopefully point you in the right direction.

https://csharp2json.io/